# getTableName not adding table prefix for custom module table only

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

We have a prefix in our Magento DB: prefix_

I am trying to get table name with prefix but it is not getting correct table name with prefix.

the code i m using is magento standard code but still not getting table name with prefix only for my custom table only. Rest is working fine.

I have install my custom module after install magento.

Here is the code how i am fetching table with prefix.

```
    <?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Invoice\Grid\Collection as SalesOrderInvoiceGridCollection;

class SalesInvoiceGridCollection {
    const SALES_ORDER_INVOICE_GRID_DATA_SOURCE = 'sales_order_invoice_grid_data_source';

    private $collection;

    public function __construct(SalesOrderInvoiceGridCollection $collection, ResourceConnection $resource) {
        $this->collection = $collection;
        $this->resource = $resource;
    }

    public function aroundGetReport(CollectionFactory $subject, \Closure $proceed, $requestName) {
        $result = $proceed($requestName);
        $connection = $this->resource->getConnection();
        $tableName = $connection->getTableName('my_custom_table');
        if (self::SALES_ORDER_INVOICE_GRID_DATA_SOURCE == $requestName) {
            if ($result instanceof $this->collection) {
                $select = $this->collection->getSelect();
                $select->joinLeft(
                    ["gstinv" => $tableName],
                    'main_table.entity_id = gstinv.invoice_id',
                    ['increment_id_with_prefix']
                );

                return $this->collection;
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have `collection` object in your function so you can get it using below code only.

```
$this->collection->getTable('my_custom_table');
```